# Adding items to the start of an object

Tags: vuejs2

I have an associate object.

```
records: {
   '15/07/2017': [],
   '16/07/2017': [], 
}
```

I want to add an extra item to the object, at the present moment I am having to use:

```
Vue.set(self.records, '17/07/2017', []);
```

The problem that I have is that the record is added at the end of the list, while I want the record to go to the front of the list. How can this be rectified?

Comment: Object keys in javascript have no guaranteed order. When you present the information you'll need to sort it, unless perhaps you use a `Map`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/796554

Comment: As hughes javascript objects do not have a particular order, its better that you use an array (if your usecase supports )which are ordered and you can use unshift() of array to add a new entry to the top off your array